# Considering an Upgrade: Mounting the Magicshine RN3000 on the RAVEMEN FR160 – A Practical Solution?

Tags: road-bike, headlights

The [RN3000](https://magicshine.com/products/rn3000-brightest-bike-light?_pos=1&_psq=rn3000&_ss=e&_v=1.0&variant=41195137728649) features an aluminum housing, contrasting with the plastic composition of the [FR160](https://www.ravemen.com/FR/FR160.html). Why consider this configuration? Presently, my [RN3000](https://magicshine.com/products/rn3000-brightest-bike-light?_pos=1&_psq=rn3000&_ss=e&_v=1.0&variant=41195137728649) is affixed to the [MJ-627](https://magicshine.com/products/magicshine%C2%AE-mj-6272-out-front-bike-mount), yet it encounters interference with the stem screws. While I could resort to a [TTA Mount](https://magicshine.com/products/tta?_pos=1&_sid=e35623cd4&_ss=r), opting for the [FR160](https://www.ravemen.com/FR/FR160.html) offers the advantage of an additional light source and increased height, ensuring the [RN3000](https://magicshine.com/products/rn3000-brightest-bike-light?_pos=1&_psq=rn3000&_ss=e&_v=1.0&variant=41195137728649) avoids contact with the stem screws. What are your thoughts on this alternative?

Comment: You may need to consider that the FR160 (a small light designed to sandwich between a bike computer and an a bike computer mount), is designed to mount a bike computer on top, which is usually considerably lighter than most lights and would not strain the top mount of the FR160 near as much as the light you intend to mount. Add to that the plastic mount of the FR160, and I would expect that the FR160 mount would fail upon hitting a bump, or even if you bumped your light with your hand. Would it mount, yes. Would it be durable, no.

Comment: @TedHohl: +1. The Garmin Edge bike computers for which the mount was originally designed are around 85g. The RN3000 is 300g, add the 55g of the FR160 and you end up with 355g. I’ve even seen Garmin Edges with broken mounts (it’s only two small plastic noses).